# Threads/tasks context switching during execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, task

I have a theoretical question about the possibility that a thread or task could get paused during its work in favor of a different thread/task.

I have an ASP.NET Core (6.0) web API server which receives requests to change internal state. lets say I have two threads running, both of which change the same data and then persist it to some external service. the code that does the actual data changes is synchronized by a lock block. assuming that the first thread entered the lock, changed the data, exited the lock then starts to persist its current copy of the data. meanwhile thread 2 enters the lock, changes the data again, exits the lock and start to persist its own copy of the data. my question is: is it possible that the second thread would finish persisting its data first in some (probably) edge case scenario? for example could the scheduler decide to pause thread1 in the middle (right after existing the lock) in a way that its copy of the data becomes old and replaces the more updated version which was saved by thread 2?

this is the basic code concept:

```
public void Update(string SomeNewState)
{
    lock(syncobj)
    {
        // this code runs on the micro-seconds scale
        
        // change internal state
        // get a copy of updated state
    }
    
    // can thread 1 pause here and allow thread 2 to perform its persisting before thread 1 gets around
    //to do it?

    PersistNewState(updatedState)
}
```

`

This is a theoretical question about threads/task scheduling. I tried many different online searches including AI chat but couldn't find any documentation about this subject.
I know it used to happen on the UI thread in winforms for example but that was due to invokes from worker threads to the UI thread and was a rather unique situation.

Clarification about threads/tasks: I`m actually asking how do they both behave (each on its own). I could use threads or tasks in different use cases and I`m trying to figure out how each one handles this scenario. for example if threads get context switch but tasks are guaranteed to complete all the way, I`ll use tasks in such cases.

Edit:
I know that execution order in general isn't deterministic in a multithreaded environment and without synchronization anything can happen in any order. However, since the lock already forces some order of execution (and I dont care which thread works first), I was wondering: could that be enough to "cheat" normal multithreaded synchronization rules and get "free" synchronization (of execution not of data safety) or is there another way to force the first thread to continue execution even though its no longer in a synchronization block?

Comment: If its not in a lock a different thread can do something in between yes.  How likely/theoretical is hard to tell. But you are talking about tasks and locks. They don't work well together most of the time. A task isn't a thread.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? All requests are served by separate threads already. `couldn't find any documentation about this subject` on the contrary *all* docs all the way back to 2000 assume multiple threads. Databases don't require locks though, session state, the `IMemoryCache` and `IDistributedCache` implementations take care of locking already, and in the cases that people need to store data in global container they typically use thread-safe containers like ConcurrentDictionary, or use a pub/sub mechanism to send changes to a single worker thread

Comment: `including AI chat` if you can't ask a good question, a probabilistic text generator won't create a good answer. ChatGPT know nothing about programming, it generates text responses based on *your* text and the data it's trained on. Other developers can guess what you may mean, based on their own experience, past questions, previous projects

Comment: *"Threads/tasks"* -- I would suggest to edit the question and remove all references of "tasks", and leave only "threads". Unless you include a second example in the question that features tasks.

Comment: Only if OS scheduler somehow interferes with thread 1, so latter stops making steps. Considering that novadays apps often run in isolated containers, i would say this is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Whenever you are writing any multi threaded code you have to assume that any code without synchronization can run in any possible ordering. The idea that a program runs thing sequentially is only valid for a single thread. Whenever multiple threads are involved all kinds of unexpected things can happen if you lack proper synchronization. I would highly recommend spending some time studding thread safety before writing any multi threaded code. There should be *plenty* of resources available.

Comment: @Ralf I`m not mixing them. @PanagiotisKanavos documentation or posts about what could cause and some example scenario of a way a context switch could happen. Completely agree about AI - bad questions would result in bad answers. Persisting is done via an external http API call. I have several solutions to that specific problem but I`m trying to dive even deeper to understand a specific multithreaded situation. I edited the question to clarify the point I`m trying to understand.

Comment: `is there another way to force the first thread to continue execution even though its no longer in a synchronization block?` - to the best of my knowledge there is not. Even within the sync block it can in principle get interrupted at any time - it holds on to its locked resources, of course. In reality threads are not interrupted very frequently when they don't block on something, but there are no guarantees that they won't be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for example could the scheduler decide to pause thread1 in the middle (right after existing the lock) in a way that its copy of the data becomes old and replaces the more updated version which was saved by thread 2?

Yes, everything after `lock` has no synchronization guarantees so you can't rely on the execution order in this case.

Note that in general `lock` and other "local" synchronization primitives in context of ASP.NET Core app in modern infrastructure have a more limited application - you can have several instances of the same web application running in parallel which can potentially require some other ways of synchronization (if needed).